# is it possiable to display telugu text in android mobile

Tags: android, textview, android-fonts

actually i have problem to display telugu text in android mobile. i am getting telugu text from sever through json parsing and i seeing text in  in logcat like

11-06 18:25:00.807: I/System.out(668):

{

id=c200,

email=అశ్విని@అశ్విని.అశ్విని,

mobile=అశ్విని,

name=అశ్విని

}

but when every i attach to the textview using ttf file like
Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),"fonts/CHILLER.ttf"); it 
shows rectangle boxess could you please any one give me suggestion

Comment: That font http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?fmid=936 ? Seems to have no special symbols for telugu. Most fonts don't support everything defined in http://www.unicode.org/charts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am  able to  display telugu text  in emulator as well as mobile. Here I am using **NTR.ttf**  font UTF16/UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a font file that:

- Has the Telugu glyphs, and
- Is either free for you to embed in an app (or is one that you have licensed to embed in an app)

Also, you can remove `getBaseContext()` and simply use `getAssets()`.